Unable to utilize already used formula for Data validation
I am working with the Access Analytic template for multi level dependant data validation drop downs.
https://accessanalytic.com.au/easiest-excel-multiple-row-dependent-drop-down-list/
But when I attempt to recreate the data validation for the cells excel throws the error
"This entry leads to an error, Try entering different values to continue"
This is despite the template already having the data validation inputted and clearly working.
I have attempted to manually recreate the template in multiple different excel environments to no avail.
Can anyone advise what issue I am having here and how to resolve it, I am working with Microsoft 365 and have attempted to use Excel 2013 as well

Hey, in your (recreated) workbook, could you check the entries in the Name Manager to see whether they match in the original one? It would be helpful if you could post a screen capture of the Name Manager and the formula that is giving the error.

Hi nklavi, this same error is thrown even when using the the unchanged template and trying to reapply the already present data validation with its example values

I see. I'm at loss here. I see that some have gotten the same error when using the similar type of validation in the web version of Microsoft 365, but worked fine under desktop. I hope some more experienced users will look into this.
